# json_decode assign specific parts to strings

Tags: php, json

I'm using json_decode on $jsontest (for demonstration purposes since it's the exact format).

The problem is I'm trying to assign filename, name, and type for attachment7 to separate variables as a string. I tried

```
$attachment7filename = $jsontest2->{'attachment7->filename'};
```

for example and the output is PHP Notice:

> Trying to get property of non-object.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
 <?php

    $jsontest = '{"attachment7":{"filename":"small.flv","name":"small.flv","type":"video/x-flv"},"attachment2":{"filename":"sample.png","name":"sample.png","type":"image/png"},"attachment6":    {"filename":"small.3gp","name":"small.3gp","type":"video/3gpp"},"attachment5":    {"filename":"small.webm","name":"small.webm","type":"video/webm"},"attachment3":    {"filename":"small.mp4","name":"small.mp4","type":"video/mp4"},"attachment1":        {"filename":"109-1new.jpeg","name":"109-    1new.jpeg","type":"image/jpeg"},"attachment4":    {"filename":"small.ogv","name":"small.ogv","type":"video/ogg"}}';

    $jsontest2 = json_decode($jsontest, true);

    $attachment7filename = $jsontest2->{'attachment7->filename'}; // should be small.flv for example
    $attachment7name = $jsontest2->{'attachment7->name'};
    $attachment7type = $jsontest2->{'attachment7->type'};

    var_dump($attachment7filename);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using curly braces (`{}`) with `object` reference like `$jsontest2->{'attachment7->filename'};` replace this`{'attachment7->filename'}` with `['attachment7']['filename'];`

here is the code

```
<?php

    $jsontest = '{"attachment7":{"filename":"small.flv","name":"small.flv","type":"video/x-flv"},"attachment2":{"filename":"sample.png","name":"sample.png","type":"image/png"},"attachment6":    {"filename":"small.3gp","name":"small.3gp","type":"video/3gpp"},"attachment5":    {"filename":"small.webm","name":"small.webm","type":"video/webm"},"attachment3":    {"filename":"small.mp4","name":"small.mp4","type":"video/mp4"},"attachment1":        {"filename":"109-1new.jpeg","name":"109-    1new.jpeg","type":"image/jpeg"},"attachment4":    {"filename":"small.ogv","name":"small.ogv","type":"video/ogg"}}';

    $jsontest2 = json_decode($jsontest, true);
//print_r($jsontest2);
    $attachment7filename = $jsontest2['attachment7']['filename']; // should be small.flv for example
    $attachment7name = $jsontest2['attachment7']['name'];
    $attachment7type = $jsontest2['attachment7']['type'];

    var_dump($attachment7filename);

    ?>
```

you can check your desired [output here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4e8bf7201285d44da39abbdcc8952f54f6cb2b32)

Comment: _Suggestion:_ You might want to add a note in your answer why it should be accessed as an array instead of an object (the `true`, argument). Just to clarify it for future visitors.